# Subprocess not capturing all stdout from Django tests run with Nose

Tags: python, django, testing, subprocess, nose

On executing tests using subprocess as follows:

```
subprocess.Popen(["./manage.py", "test", "-x", "--settings=settings_test"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Only the initial part of the test output is captured. So I get the returned tuple

```
 ("\x1b[32mUsing database: develop\x1b[0m\n\x1b[33mRunning tests against sqlite3 in memory database\x1b[0m\nnosetests --verbosity 1 -x\nCreating test database for alias 'default'...\nDestroying test database for alias 'default'...\n", None)
```

However, this misses the key final three lines

```
Ran 260 tests in 70.131s

OK (SKIP=1)
```

Is there a way to capture this output using subprocess?

Comment: Hey, do you how to simulate server restarts in using `subprocess`? is your code uploaded in github so I can see it?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the summary is written to stderr, so you need to catch that too.

```
sub = subprocess.Popen(
        ["./manage.py", "test", "-x", "--settings=settings_test"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = sub.communicate()
# err should have the summary
```